# How safe is it to use tor on a monitored network?

Tags: anonymity, server

So in a shape this question has been asked but mine is more specific. If It is a work network that blocks a huge number of websites and services, you can use tor to circumvent the blocks but can the network monitor still see what you do? Even if its a personal computer(with no work software)? I know they have some type of constant third party monitoring system where apparently they can see any screen on the network? Note this question is more being asked to learn the limits of tor on secured networks like work or school, and is theorectical.

Comment: If it's really your personal device and there is no work software installed, they won't be able to see your screen nor read your Tor traffic. However, they will likely still be able to recognize that you're using Tor based on traffic patterns and the addresses you're connecting to.

Comment: Adding on to [tlng05's](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/54791/tlng05) comment, tor nodes are [generally known](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/) by network monitors and often blocked in the workplace. It is also easily identifiable by analyzing your network logs.

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario the network provider (and ISP) is able to determine that you are using Tor. This might raise a flag which could initiate technical (e.g. IP blocking) or organizational processes (e.g. questioning).

There are technical approaches to de-anonymize Tor traffic (to identify the involved peers). Furthermore there are attacks against the involved cryptographic mechanisms possible. But all those things are usually way too complex and remain a task followed by law enforcement and intelligence services only.

Therefore it is highly doubtable that it is possible with common free or commercial proxy and sniffing software to capture screen or browser content during a Tor session.

Comment: This answer would be stronger if it responded to the OP's concerns that the employer can view the computer screen and generally "see what you do".